# difference between logistic regression and binary logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, r, logistic-regression, xgboost, gbm

In xgboost R package, there are two objectives given with booster `gbtree`.

1. `reg:logistic`
2. `binary:logistic`

See,page 22 (first 2 lines) https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xgboost/xgboost.pdf

I was wondering, what is the difference between these two methods?

Comment: See also https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/9802/55122

Answer (score 6):

`binary:logistic` is used for binary classification where the target variable takes **binary output** [0, 1]

`reg:logistic` is used for regression where the target variable is **continuous** between [0, 1]

Quote from xgboost doc:

`We use linear regression here, if we want use objective = reg:logistic logistic regression, the label needed to be pre-scaled into [0,1]`

https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/tree/master/demo/regression

Comment: Would be nice if you could add the objective in its mathematical form